# Several copyFields on schema

Tags: apache, search, solr, lucene, search-engine

I have several copyField tags on my schema but just one works.

```
  <field name="title" type="text_en_test" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title_without_synonym" type="text_en_without_synonym" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title_stems" type="text_en_stems" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title_lowercase" type="lowercase" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="title_text_general" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_without_synonym" maxChars="30000" />
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_stems" maxChars="30000" />
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_lowercase" maxChars="30000" />
  <copyField source="title" dest="title_text_general" maxChars="30000" />
```

In this case, just "title_without_synonym" works. Considering that all these 'fieldType's exists, what I'm doing wrong?

The idea is to use several preprocessing types on query time (with different weights) to improve accuracy.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything explicitly wrong - are you actually indexing content into `title`, and does that field have a stored value if you return the document? Have you reloaded your schema after adding the copyField instructions?

Comment: @MatsLindh yes! Here's an example of document, with the command I use to index it. https://pastebin.com/CNMeNARR

Comment: Check out a comparation of both scenarios, using debugQuery: https://pastebin.com/AxK5vxTH

Comment: Your paste does not show what is being returned as fields on the document.

Comment: @MatsLindh Please, check again. Included

Comment: Please include all the fields - not just the title field. It's kind of important to see what's being indexed into the fields, since you might have different processing for the field that is not matching anything on querying and indexing, meaning that there _actually_ isn't a _match_, while the data is being indexed into the field. You can also use the analysis part of the Solr admin page to see why it's not matching.

Comment: Even including the 'description_text_general' it doesn't return anything. https://pastebin.com/RSNuaQS7 . Do you mean using all of those fields declared on a single query?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159675/discussion-between-matslindh-and-denis-candido).